# merge two lists in one , O(1) time complexity

Tags: list, complexity-theory

i would like to ask how is it possible to merge two unsorted lists into one unsorted list in constant time in C since we need a while loop to get all the elements.

ex:

```
List1: 2 5 1 4 3
List2: 5 9 4 2 5 7 8
List3: elements of the two lists,don't care about order
```

Don't judge me i'm a beginner.

Comment: Please clarify how you are implementing a list. This will help others provide better answers. Providing a working example of your code would help further.

Comment: i din't really understand the logic adriano...could you please tell me more?

Comment: would it work if i take as a parameter the tail of the first list and the head of the second and make the tail point to the head of the second?

Comment: @programfrog Yes, make the tail of the first list point to the head of the second list instead of to NULL.

Comment: You tagged this question with C, although the programming language in which you will finally implement this has not much to do with the problem.

Comment: @JensGustedt so what?

Comment: @programfrog, the tags of a question are meant to guide the right people to your question, here they were misguiding.

Comment: @JensGustedt okay i'll remove the tag

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: go and read about linked list data structures. All this stuff is perfectly common.

---

The minimal requirement for a genuinely O(1) append is that you have mutable linked lists with constant-time access to the tail.

So, the simplest possible linked list is:

```
struct ListNode {
  struct ListNode *next;
  int data; /* or void*, or whatever */
};

typedef struct ListNode *SinglyLinkedList;
```

ie, you just hold a pointer to the first element of your list. In this case, getting to the tail is linear time (`O(n)`), so you can't do what you want. However, if instead we use

```
struct ListHeadTail {
    struct ListNode *head;
    struct ListNode *tail;
    /* could keep length here as well, if you want it */
};
```

then inserting to the list is slightly harder, but you can easily do a constant-time append:

```
struct ListHeadTail append(struct ListHeadTail *first,
                           struct ListHeadTail *second) {
    struct ListHeadTail result;

    /* special cases first, where either first or second is empty */
    if (first->head == NULL) {
        result = *second;
        second->head = second->tail = NULL;
    } else if (second->head == NULL) {
        result = *first;
        first->head = first->tail = NULL;
    } else {
        result.head = first->head;
        result.tail = second->tail;
        first->tail->next = second->head;
        first->head = first->tail = NULL;
        second->head = second->tail = NULL;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Other common structures are doubly-linked lists - again with a sentinel node rather than a having `head->prev == tail->next == NULL`.

Comment: i'm not asking you about making of the lists...i'm talking about a function that's merging them

Comment: You didn't specify in adequate detail what you mean by a list. If you mean something like the second one - any singly-linked list where you have constant-time access to the tail - or a circular doubly-linked list etc, _and_ you're allowed to damage your input lists, then the answer to your question is trivial. So trivial, I'd assumed you were confused about the data structure rather than the algorithm (to the extent they're seperable).

Comment: i'm very sorry i asked something so stupid ...it's okay to be nice to people you know even the stupid ones like me

Comment: I am (trying to) help, but you're not giving me much to work with. There ^ is a sample solution for _one_ type of linked list, but I don't know if that's the same as _your_ type of linked list. If you're using something else, what? There are lots of ways of storing a list, and you won't say what you have, where you got it, or what you understand about it.

Comment: it's a singly linked list with fiels head,tail and next...two lists like this one a function like this one:

merging(*listnode tail1,*listnode head1,*listnode head2){
   *listnode head3;
    tail1->next=head2;
    head3=head1;
    return head3;


}
would be okay?

Comment: So you don't even have a structure, just raw head & tail pointers? Your algorithm will work, just note that `head1` is still valid outside the call, but that node is now part of another list. This will make memory management hard, and is why I cleared out the input lists in my version (so the nodes are owned and reachable from only one head)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the data structure in memory and whether you can modify the existing lists.

If you can modify the existing lists, then you can ask `List1` for it's last element (which is O(1) is the list header has a pointer to the end of the list) and then it's simply a matter of `List1->last->next = List2->head`. Afterwards, iterating over `List1` will iterate over all elements.

If you must not change `List1`, then you have to copy the list; this is tricky to do with O(1) but still possible if you keep all elements in a single memory area (i.e. you don't use pointers to nodes; instead you keep all nodes in an array). In this case, you allocate memory for the nodes of both lists and then you can populate the result with two times `memcopy()`. Granted, `memcopy()` isn't really O(1) but with current CPUs (which can copy gigabytes per second), you usually don't notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If what you desire is for something to *behave* as a concatenated list, you can indeed do so by creating a ConcatenatedList class that is constructed from two existing List classes.  If you are working with pure C as opposed to C++, the notion of a class may need to be fudged a bit, but structurally, the idea is the same.

The ConcatenatedList class can have two attributes: a header attribute, which is nothing more than a reference to the first List, and a tail attribute, which is nothing more than a reference to the second List.

You then mimic the methods of the basic List class with ConcatenatedList.  To access the kth element of the ConcatenatedList, you try something like this:

`if (k < header->size()) {
    return header->getElement(k);
 }
 return tail->getElement(k - header->size());`

The rest of the coding should be straight-forward from there.

Using this approach, the concatenation process will be O(1).

It is worth noting that the answer presented by (not) Useless is also valid, but it assumes a LinkedList structure to your lists, whereas this approach does not have that requirement.  It is possible however, that after repeated concatenations, this approach will begin to look like a LinkedList implementation in terms of performance.